# Onclick para enviar informacion

Tags: html, href

Tengo un boton y con el evento clic necesito que se realice basicamente como la accion de un href, ya que mediante un link enviara informacion a otra pagina, sin embargo quiero que se ejecute y en lugar de abrir una nueva ventana se abra una alerta diciendo proceso terminado y me mantenga en la misma pagina.

```
<button type="submit" onclick= "window.open('http://53.18.19.1/module/ps_buybuttonlite/RedirectManager?id_product=23&action=1&id_product_attribute=null','_blank')">ENVIAR DATOS</button>
```

Comment: No termino de entender muy bien lo que quieres hacer, sí lo que quieres es redireccionarte, sería en vez de `windows.open` es `location.href = "enlace"`

Comment: necesito que al hacer clic en el boton se ejecute una url pero que no realice ningun target(_blank,_self) sino que solamente se ejecute dicha url y con eso invoco un alert; con el enlace lo que hago es agregar a un carrito de compras entonces el alert dira producto agregado al carrito de compras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias mandar un mensaje de tipo alert, no se si es lo que necesitas. Te dejo un ejemplo :)

```
<button type="submit" href="http://53.18.19.1/module/ps_buybuttonlite/RedirectManager?id_product=23&action=1&id_product_attribute=null" onClick='alert("Compra agregada!")'>ENVIAR DATOS</a>
```

Es solo una idea.Espero que te ayude!

Answer (score 1):

Gracias me ayudo a guiarme, resolví este problema cargando el href en una iframe con display: none, de esta forma levantaba el alert y ejecutaba el href sin salirme de la pagina.

```
<iframe name="show" style="display: none;"></iframe>

<a href="http://www.misitio.com/RedirectManager?id_product=80&action=1&id_product_attribute=null" class="btn btn-success" onclick='alert("Compra agregada!")' target="show">AGREGAR</a>
```